# Decrypting string in Python encrypted in C# AES 256

Tags: python, c#, encryption, aes, pycryptodome

Data is being encrypted in C# and send to us, I need to write a Python code to decrypt it.

Here is the C# code for encryption:

```
public static string EncryptString(string key, string plainText)
        {
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            byte[] array;
            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
                aes.IV = iv;
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter((Stream)cryptoStream))
                        {
                            streamWriter.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        array = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(array);
        }
```

Here is how the decryption works in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static string DecryptString(string key, string text)
        {
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
                aes.IV = iv;
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader((Stream)cryptoStream))
                        {
                            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
    
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DecryptString("b14ca5898a4e4133bbce2ea2315a1916","Qri3376EFpjxJdBBauGZLg=="));
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to decrypt it using Cryptodome, but it doesn't seem to work, either due to incorrect padding, or something else. Here is my Python code for testing purposes:

```
import hashlib
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
import base64
from Crypto import Random
import Crypto.Util.Padding as padding


password = base64.b64decode('somekey') # changed

iv = Random.new().read(16) # Because C# seems to be using Random as well
# print(iv)
aes = AES.new(password, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
text = 'Qri3376EFpjxJdBBauGZLg==' # It should be '1'
text = base64.b64decode(text)
print(text)
print(aes.decrypt(text))
print(aes.decrypt(text).decode("UTF-16"))
```

This seemingly works, but returns gibberish:

> b'B\xb8\xb7\xdf\xbe\x84\x16\x98\xf1%\xd0Aj\xe1\x99.'
> b'\x17\xcd5a\x1b-.\xb4h{\x9a\xb2}{R\xf7'
> 횥濢빝봅ի䁁ẹ

And, if changed to this, as suggested in similar threads:

```
decryptedPadded = aes.decrypt(text)
decrypted = padding.unpad(decryptedPadded, 16)
print(decrypted.decode('utf-16'))
```

it returns:

> ValueError: Padding is incorrect.

Not sure what to do next

Comment: For decryption, the same key and IV must be used as for encryption, i.e. `password = b'b14ca5898a4e4133bbce2ea2315a1916'` (which is actually a key) and `iv = b'\0' * 16`. Also, the data must be unpadded before UTF-8 decoding: `padding.unpad(aes.decrypt(text), 16).decode('utf-8')`. Then decryption works. Note that a static IV is a vulnerability (as is a hex encoded string that is UTF-8 encoded and applied as key).

Comment: That's true, but compared to using AES CBC for transport security it is a minor vulnerability. Plaintext & padding oracle attacks!

Comment: @Topaco, thanks, this works! The whole algorithm will work in closed-off machine without unauthorized access possible, so this risk is acceptable. Thank you!

Unfortunately, I can't set yours as a correct answer or upvote it, but it works - if anyone sees this post, please pay attention.